# New to JS, trying to put together Rock Paper Scissors Game

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JS and have been challenged to put together a Rock Paper Scissors game. Can anyone give me any pointers as to what I've put together so far? does it seem logical?

I believe that I'm on the right track, but I need some guidance as to what to do to make this code and more readable.

```
function getPlayerMove() {
    var playerMove = prompt("Please choose either 'rock', 'paper', or 'scissors'.");
    alert("You have chosen" + playerMove + ".");
    return playerMove;
};

 function getComputerMove() {
    var computerMove = Math.random();
    if (computerMove < 0.33) {
        alert("The computer has chosen rock.");
        computerMove === "rock";
    } else if (computerMove < 0.66) {
        alert("The computer has chosen paper.");
        computerMove === "paper";
    } else {
        alert("The computer has chosen scissors.");
        computerMove === "scissors";
    }
    return computerMove;
}

function getWinner(playerMove, computerMove) {
    var playerWins === 0;
    var computerWins === 0;
    if (playerMove === "rock") {
        if (computerMove === "scissors") {
            alert("Rock beats scissors. The player has won.");
            return "player"
            playerWins++;
        };
        else if (computerMove === "paper") {
        alert("Paper beats rock. The computer has won.");
        return "computer";
        computerWins++;
        };
        else {
            alert("Both choose rock. It's a tie!")
            };
        };
        else if (playerMove === "scissors") {
            if (computerMove === "scissors") {
            alert("Both choose scissors. It's a tie!");
        }
        else if (computerMove === "paper") {
            alert("Scissors beats paper. The player has won.");
            return "player";
            playerWins++;
            {
        else {
            alert("Rock beats paper. The computer has won.")
            return "computer";
            computerWins++;
        };
    };
    else {
        if (computerMove === "scissors") {
            alert("Scissors beats paper. The computer has won.");
            return "computer"
            computerWins++;
        };
        else if (computerMove === "paper") {
            alert("Both choose paper. It's a tie!");
        };
        else {
            alert("Paper beats rock. The player has won!");
            return "player";
            playerWins++;
        };
     };
};

function playToFive {
    if (playerWins === 5) {
        alert("Player has won 5 times! You win!");
    }
    else if (computerWins === 5) {
        alert("Computer has won 5 times! You lose!");
    }
    else 
        getPlayerMove;
        getcomputerMove;
        getWinner;
    };
    }
```

Comment: what is this.   var playerWins === 0;
    var computerWins === 0; and  else 
        getPlayerMove;
        getcomputerMove;
        getWinner;
    };?

Comment: `return "player"
            playerWins++;´

.playerWins++ could never be reached.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to make playerWins and computerWins into global variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would add an array to hold the options. And that should have an effect in making the rest of the code more readable. In general the less string you have around the better. Adding the choices into an array in specific order also allows you to compare numbers (index) rather than strings which should make the rest of the script much easier. (With the array I'm trying to make up for lack of enumerators in JS)

```
var choices = ["Paper", "Scissors", "Rock"]; //From weakest to toughest
```

That can help you replace a bunch of strings.

Also the get computer move can be simplified by selecting a random number that corresponds to the array index.

```
return choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
```

I'm sure there is more but this was just a quick look at it that I haven't tested.

--The more I look at it the more stuff I see .. but you only asked for guidance so I wont spoil your thinking..

Comment: Thank you anyway. I know that this is a poorly-written piece of code, so I am trying to refine my reasoning as I'm just starting out. But I do really appreciate your suggestions of an array to contain the choices.

Answer (score 0):

### Function returns

Everything looks pretty good except the `getWinner` and `playToFive` functions. Remember, when a function returns something, the execution of that function stops, so stuff like:

```
    if (computerMove === "scissors") {
        alert("Rock beats scissors. The player has won.");
        return "player"; // the execution stops here
        playerWins++;
    };
```

won't work as you expected - `playerWins` will never get incremented.

---

### Unreachable parts

Next you have `if (playerMove === "rock") {` and then inside it:

```
else if (playerMove === "scissors") {
```

which will never happen, of course, because if the code get inside the first loop, it means the player chose `rock`, so the comparison with `scissors` is irrelevant.

---

### Handling Ties

The whole thing with ties can be handled differently to avoid repetition:

```
else if (playerMove === "scissors") {
        if (computerMove === "scissors") {
        alert("Both choose scissors. It's a tie!");
    }
```

can cover all the cases when written like:

```
if (playerMove === computerMove) {
    alert("Both choose " + computerMove + ". It's a tie!");
}
```

---

### Optimizing `getWinner`

We can remove all the returns because you're not using the function return values anywhere.
The whole function can be optimized to:

```
function getWinner(playerMove, computerMove) {
    if (playerMove === computerMove) {
        alert("Both choose " + computerMove + ". It's a tie!");
    }
    // no more ties below this line
    else if (playerMove === "rock") {
        if (computerMove === "scissors") {
            alert("Rock beats scissors. The player has won.");
            playerWins++;
        };
        else { // no need to specfically check for "paper" 
               // because it's all that remains now
            alert("Paper beats rock. The computer has won.");
            computerWins++;
        };
    }
    else if (playerMove === "scissors") {
        if (computerMove === "paper") {
            alert("Scissors beats paper. The player has won.");
            playerWins++;
        } // this bracket was wrong
        else {
            alert("Rock beats paper. The computer has won.")
            computerWins++;
        };
    }
    else {
        if (computerMove === "scissors") {
            alert("Scissors beats paper. The computer has won.");
            computerWins++;
        }
        else {
            alert("Paper beats rock. The player has won!");
            playerWins++;
        };
     }
}
```

---

### Game Loop

The next big thing is that you need to have a loop - the game needs to repeat until someone wins. This also means the counter variables should be outside the `getWinner` function, otherwise they will always reset to zero. Anyway, the loop can be the `playToFive` function, and to achieve looping, you need to call it every time there's more to play:

```
function playToFive() {
  if (playerWins === 5) {
    alert("Player has won 5 times! You win!");
  }
  else if (computerWins === 5) {
    alert("Computer has won 5 times! You lose!");
  }
  else 
    getPlayerMove();   // don't forget the brackets - we need to call 
    getcomputerMove(); // these three functions, not
    getWinner();       // just put their bodies here

    // finally, this is where the loop happens:
    playToFive();
  }
}
```

---

### Live Demo:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGQKxe?editors=001

Comment: Thank you so much for laying this out so completely for me! I can't thank you enough!! This is really going to help me understand all the intricacies of JS a lot better. AGAIN, THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Hey, no problem, I'm glad I could help. I still might've missed a thing or two, but at least now you have a working code to start with. You're welcome. :)